# Adding HTML in Ionic modals

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm using the following ionic example to create modals in ionic: http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#modals

I'm using the following code to output my content for each modal: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-preview-app/blob/master/src/pages/modals/basic/pages.ts

How would I go about outputting HTML in the following code for one of my items without it outputting the HTML as plain text?

```
name: 'Gollum',
        quote: 'Sneaky little hobbitses!',
        image: 'assets/img/avatar-gollum.jpg',
        items: [
          { title: 'Race', note: 'Hobbit' },
          { title: 'Culture', note: 'River Folk' },
          { title: 'Alter Ego', note: 'Smeagol' }
        ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Use HTML in this code

Like: Here we are using two tags ( paragraph and strong tag) in quotes

```
name: 'Gollum',
    quote: '<p><strong>Sneaky little hobbitses!</strong></p>',
    image: 'assets/img/avatar-gollum.jpg',
    items: [
      { title: 'Race', note: 'Hobbit' },
      { title: 'Culture', note: 'River Folk' },
      { title: 'Alter Ego', note: 'Smeagol' }
    ]
```

and You Can Display without html

Like:

```
<div class="item item-text-wrap" [innerHTML]="post.quote"></div>
```

> Note - Where post is a variable which stores the following data.

The output will come like that

> **Sneaky little hobbitses!**

Comment: Awesome! Works perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: Great @Breon, would you like my answer, please.